# Activity.onDestroy being called on every back button push

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I am testing my android app that is in development.

It contains a single MainActivity

I noticed through testing that onDestroy was being called every time I push the back button.

I thought that this was weird. So I created a fresh empty activity app using android studio, and added no code. Just a simple hello world.

Even in this hello world app, onDestroy is being called everytime I press back.

I am running a Samsung S4 and I have not reason to believe that it is resource starved. What is going on here?

I tried setting android:launchMode to all available values in AndroidManifest.xml, and none of that worked....

Answer (score 0):

Activity getting destroyed whenever you are pressing back button i.e android default behavior. This is how code flows.
 override onBackPressed inside your Activity

```
   /**
     * called when user press back button on device
     */
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Go inside onBackPressed  which lies inside FragmentActivity which shows that it will first pop all fragments from activity and then it will finish activity.

```
   /**
     * Take care of popping the fragment back stack or finishing the activity
     * as appropriate.
     */
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!mFragments.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()) {
        supportFinishAfterTransition();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is normal and expected behavior that OnDestroy() is called after the back button is pressed. This is a standard part of the Android Activity Lifecycle. You can read about the lifecycle here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

I would not recommend overriding the back button behavior as jitesh has suggested unless you have good reason. Users will expect that your app is "closed" (destroyed) once the back button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want OnDestroy() not being called everytime you tap back button:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // super.onBackPressed(); // remove this line
}
```